# Checking if a KeyValuePair array contains a specific pair that meets certain criteria?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which is receiving the following input: `params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] paramsToUse`

In the method receiving the above input, is there a neat clean inline way of verifying that:

1. `paramsToUse` contains a KeyValuePair where the key is some specific
   string, e.g. `customerId`, and ...
2. The value in that specific KeyValuePair (for which the above condition is true) is valid when verified through another static method that returns true/false, e.g. `CheckIfCustomerIdIsValid(string customerIdToValidate)`

One obvious way is to do a foreach loop over all the elements in `paramsToUse` and verify if a KeyValuePair exists which meets the above criteria, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do the same using LINQ perhaps ?

EDIT:

To make further clear, I want to see if there's a way to shorten the code below:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in paramsToUse)
{
    if (pair.Key == "customerId" && CheckIfCustomerIdIsValid(pair.Value) == true)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Output would be the value of `found`

Comment: Perhaps 1) get the KVPs where 'the key is some specific string' and if there are any then 2) see if those match the condition?

Comment: Hmm .. is it possible to pass in dictionary instead of key value pair?  It’s better to filter out some unnecessary search first ..

Comment: are you looking for this `               bool flag = dict.TryGetValue(dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "customerId"), out value) == true ? CheckIfCustomerIdIsValid(value) : false; ` ? @Ahmad

Comment: @viveknuna, it's not a dictionary

Comment: `bool found = (paramsToUse.Where(pair.Key == "customerId").FirstOrDefault()?.Select(p => CheckIfCustomerIdIsValid(p.Value)) ?? false) == true;`

Comment: `bool flag = kvp.Key == "customerId" ? CheckIfCustomerIdIsValid(kvp.Value) : false;`?

Comment: `paramsToUse.Contains(kvp => CheckIfCustomerIdisValid(kvp.Value))`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. To make it lexically shorter, you can use LINQ:

```
bool found = paramsToUse.Any(pair => pair.Key == "customerId" 
    && CheckIfCustomerIdIsValid(pair.Value));
```

This will basically execute the same code but hide the loop in the Any method.